# How can I link Jekyll blog to my existing site

Tags: jekyll

So I'm hosting a website from github, and I want to add a blog section to it, therefore, I chose Jekyll.
And the problem is on my main page I add a Blog section to link it to the Jekyll autogenerated html site, and it doesnt show any of the css, just only shows pure html
How does I fix this problem?? Thanks
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ujW.png)

```
<header>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#homePage">Home</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#aboutMe">About me</a></li>
      <li> <a href="resume/UyenDinh-resume.pdf" target="_blank"> Resume </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#projects"> Projects </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/myblog/_site/jekyll/update/2019/01/18/welcome-to-jekyll.html"> Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the connection between Jekyll, your existing site, and the CSS files?

Comment: yess, my website is in /portfolio and I generated Jekyll in /portfolio/myblog 
I have my CSS file in /portfolio/css and Jekyll autogenerated css is in /portfolio/myblog/_site/assets/main.css

Comment: Oh I got what you mean, I can fix it now. Thanks :)